# In this example of fuzzy c-means, what is the difference between "sigma" and "center" for the clusters?

Tags: comparison, unsupervised-learning, notation, clustering, fuzzy-logic

In this [example](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_cmeans.html), what exactly do "Cluster" and "Sigma" mean? (They chose random coordinates for the three centroids of the groups)

- **Centers:** Cluster centers, returned as a `JxN` array, where `J` is the number of clusters and `N` is the number of data dimensions.
- **Sigma:** Range of influence of cluster centers for each data dimension, returned as an `N`-element row vector. All cluster centers have the same set of sigma values.

Please, elaborate on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you link to, the *sigma* parameter has got nothing to do with the clustering; it is only used to generate sample data for illustration. It defines the spread of cluster elements around the (pre-defined) centroid of each cluster.

This is done for demonstration only: you generate clusters which you know exist, and then check that the cluster algorithm can detect those clusters correctly. In normal centroid-based clustering the centroid does not have a specified range -- each data point it simply assigned to its nearest centroid, however far away it it.